# email function not sending

Tags: php, email

Hi guys I am building a email confirmation system and for that I need the email() function but is not working 
This is my code:

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Activation Paolo.M346 system";
$from = 'no-reply@techaviationflight.com';
$message = 'Your Activation key is '.$token.' Please Click On This link 
<a href="/folder/folder_system%20/logics/mailvalidation.php? 
id='.$user_id.'&token='.$token.'">Here</a>to activate your account.';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $mail . ">\r\n";
$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if ($result)return true;
else return false;
```

I have tried all things possible from checking with

`error_get_last()`
`var_dump()`
but I can not identify the error

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, your link isn't going to work... needs to be an absolute (include the https:// part).  Other than that it looks good.

In fact, I ran it on my server and I did indeed get mail.  The issue is in your system config, check the mail server set up.  If you need help with that, assuming you are on a *nix host ask over on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes thanks for the link I will include the absolute link . I am hosting on a one.com hosting server

Comment: @GiorgioBella I ran your exact code, putting in my email as the `$to`, mail is delivered.  Could be SPF, could be you need to use a smart host and phpmailer, dunno.  Check with 1and1.  But your code works.

Comment: thanks at least the code is correct so ok let see what I can do

Comment: @vanivan contacted my hosting support they set up the server in the proper way